# Mapping non-contiguous physical memory to userspace

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, mmap

I had recently been reading Linux Device Drivers 3rd edition, and had reached chapter 15: Memory Mapping and DMA.

I had also come across [linux-kernel-labs](https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/), specifically their exercises in the [Memory mapping lab](https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/refs/heads/master/labs/memory_mapping.html#mapping-contiguous-physical-memory-to-userspace).

I tried doing the [second exercise](https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/refs/heads/master/labs/memory_mapping.html#mapping-non-contiguous-physical-memory-to-userspace), which is to implement a device driver that maps non-contiguous physical memory (e.g. obtained via `vmalloc()`) to userspace.

It read in the book that `vmalloc()` does not obtain physically contiguous memory, so each page needs to be mapped separately.

Here is my try -

```c
/*
 * PSO - Memory Mapping Lab(#11)
 *
 * Exercise #2: memory mapping using vmalloc'd kernel areas
 */

#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/vmalloc.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/sched/mm.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
#include <asm/io.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/seq_file.h>


MODULE_DESCRIPTION("simple mmap driver");
MODULE_AUTHOR("PSO");
MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

#define MY_MAJOR    42

/* how many pages do we actually vmalloc */
#define NPAGES      16

/* character device basic structure */
static struct cdev mmap_cdev;

/* pointer to the vmalloc'd area, rounded up to a page boundary */
static char *vmalloc_area;

static int my_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
    return 0;
}

static int my_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
    return 0;
}

static int my_mmap(struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
    int i;
    long length = vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start;
    unsigned long start = vma->vm_start;
    char *vmalloc_area_ptr = vmalloc_area;
    unsigned long pfn;

    if (length > NPAGES * PAGE_SIZE)
        return -EIO;

    /* TODO 1: map pages individually */

    for (i = 0; i < length; i += PAGE_SIZE) {
        pfn = vmalloc_to_pfn(vmalloc_area_ptr + i); 
        remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start + i, pfn, PAGE_SIZE, vma->vm_page_prot);
    }

    return 0;
}

static const struct file_operations mmap_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = my_open,
    .release = my_release,
    .mmap = my_mmap,
};

static int __init my_init(void)
{
    int ret = 0;
    int i;

    ret = register_chrdev_region(MKDEV(MY_MAJOR, 0), 1, "maps");
    if (ret < 0) {
        pr_err("could not register region\n");
        goto out;
    }

    /* TODO 1: allocate NPAGES using vmalloc */

    vmalloc_area = (char *) vmalloc(NPAGES * PAGE_SIZE);
    if (!vmalloc_area) {
        pr_err("Failed to allocate vmalloc area\n");
        ret = -ENOMEM;
        goto out_unreg;
    }

    /* TODO 1: mark pages as reserved */
    
    for (i = 0; i < NPAGES * PAGE_SIZE; i += PAGE_SIZE) {
        SetPageReserved(vmalloc_to_page((void*) vmalloc_area + i)); 
    }

    /* TODO 1: write data in each page */

    for (i = 0; i < NPAGES * PAGE_SIZE; i += PAGE_SIZE) {
        vmalloc_area[i + 0] = 0xdd; 
        vmalloc_area[i + 1] = 0xcc; 
        vmalloc_area[i + 2] = 0xbb; 
        vmalloc_area[i + 3] = 0xaa; 
    }

    cdev_init(&mmap_cdev, &mmap_fops);
    mmap_cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;
    ret = cdev_add(&mmap_cdev, MKDEV(MY_MAJOR, 0), 1);
    if (ret < 0) {
        pr_err("could not add device\n");
        goto out_vfree;
    }

    return 0;

out_vfree:
    vfree(vmalloc_area);
out_unreg:
    unregister_chrdev_region(MKDEV(MY_MAJOR, 0), 1);
out:
    return ret;
}

static void __exit my_exit(void)
{
    int i;

    cdev_del(&mmap_cdev);

    /* TODO 1: clear reservation on pages and free mem.*/

    if (vmalloc_area) {
        for (i = 0; i < NPAGES * PAGE_SIZE; i += PAGE_SIZE) {
            ClearPageReserved(vmalloc_to_page((void*)vmalloc_area + i)); 
        }
        vfree(vmalloc_area);
    }

    unregister_chrdev_region(MKDEV(MY_MAJOR, 0), 1);
}

module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_exit);
```

The point of writing the first 4 bytes of each page is so I can test for those values in user-space after mapping the memory.

Here is the program that I wrote to test this driver -

```c
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(void) {
    int fd, i, page_size = getpagesize();
    void* mapped_memory = NULL;

    fd = open("/dev/maps0", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("Failed to open /dev/maps\n");
        return -1;
    }
    mapped_memory = mmap(NULL, page_size*16, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    close(fd);
    if (mapped_memory == MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("Mapping failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Mapped memory is at %p\n", mapped_memory);
    printf("[%x]\n", ((char*)mapped_memory)[0]);
   
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, when I load the driver and try to test it with the program, it crashes and I get the following output -

```
Mapped memory is at 0x7f502b436000
Bus error (core dumped)
```

Can anyone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

P.S. I know the book uses the `nopage` function of `vm_operations_struct`, but I wanted to follow the lab and try doing it my own way.

Comment: Bus error is used on some CPUs to signal an unaligned access. x86 is one arch that doesn't do that, but instead emulates the unaligned access at the cost of performance and atomic operations. What is the pointer value you received from `mmap()`? What if you flush stdout after outputting the four bytes, just to verify which of them causes the bus error?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thanks for your comment. I updated the code in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR: use `MAP_SHARED`.**

There is [a check in `remap_pfn_range()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10/source/mm/memory.c#L2289) that ensures that if a mapping is copy-on-write (CoW), the requested range to remap must be exactly from `vma->vm_start` to `vma->vm_end` (i.e. it has to be physically contiguous).

```c
    /* [...]
     *
     * There's a horrible special case to handle copy-on-write
     * behaviour that some programs depend on. We mark the "original"
     * un-COW'ed pages by matching them up with "vma->vm_pgoff".
     * See vm_normal_page() for details.
     */
    if (is_cow_mapping(vma->vm_flags)) {
        if (addr != vma->vm_start || end != vma->vm_end)
            return -EINVAL;
        vma->vm_pgoff = pfn;
    }
```

A mapping is considered CoW if its `vma->vm_flags` don't have `VM_SHARED` set and have `VM_MAYWRITE` set (i.e. the mapping is not shared and may be made writable through `mprotect`).

In your case, the VMA is considered CoW and the check fails because you are mapping one page at a time, so you will never match both `vma->vm_start` and `vma->vm_end`. Your `remap_pfn_range()` is therefore failing with `-EINVAL`, and you are missing it because you don't check the return value for error.

You have 3 options:

1. Make userspace `mmap` the whole area with `MAP_SHARED`.
2. Make userspace `mmap` single pages separately with `MAP_PRIVATE`.
3. Remove `VM_MAYWRITE` from `vma->vm_flags` before mapping the pages to userspace to disallow making the page writeable in the future (i.e. with `mprotect`), which will in turn make it non-CoW.

Number 1 above is what IMHO makes the most sense and (from what I've seen) the most common option when mapping special devices.

---

P.S.: note that `printf("[%x]\n", ((char*)mapped_memory)[0]);` is wrong, it will read a single `char` (one byte) and promote it to `int` with sign extension so you'll get `[ffffffdd]`. You should do `((unsigned*)mapped_memory)[0])` instead if you wish to get `[aabbccdd]`.

Comment: That solved it. Thanks man!